# makefile not updating .o file with respectively with .h file

Tags: c, makefile

I have following make file :-

```
VER = Debug
CC = gcc
objectfiles = Getstr.o ui.o ustreqsol.o main.o
pkg = `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` 

obj = $(addprefix objs/,$(objectfiles))

../$(VER)/Calculator: $(obj)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(obj) $(pkg)

./objs/ui.o:ui.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(pkg)

./objs/main.o:main.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(pkg)

./objs/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    -rm ../$(VER)/Calculator
    -rm /objs/*
```

and follwing files in my src dir:-

```
$ ls 
Getstr.c  main.c  Makefile  objs  ui.c  ui.h  ustreqsol.c  ustreqsol.h
```

objs is directory. Whenver I change ustreqsol.h file it compiles ustreqsol.c file but not in case for ui.h file

```
$ touch ustreqsol.h
$ make
gcc -c -o objs/ustreqsol.o ustreqsol.c
gcc -o ../Debug/Calculator objs/Getstr.o objs/ui.o objs/ustreqsol.o objs/main.o `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` 
$ make
make: '../Debug/Calculator' is up to date.
$ touch ui.h
$ make
make: '../Debug/Calculator' is up to date.
```

As a noob in makefiles i have no idea why is this happening

Comment: `./objs/%.o: %.c %.h` - That says "rebuild `x.o` if `x.c` or `x.h` have changed".

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth but When I change ui.h it should  rebuild ui.o but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason ui.c is not being rebuilt is because you explictly said ui.h is not a dependency:

```
./objs/ui.o:ui.c
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(pkg)
```

For the general dependency you have set up:

```
./objs/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

The dependency list only takes effect for files that you didn't explicitly set them for, such as ustreqsol.c.

You need to add targets for each object file specifying the dependencies for each one.  The targets can be blank, as the `%.o` target will fill in what to do.

For example:

```
./objs/ustreqsol.o: ustreqsol.c ustreqsol.h ui.h

./objs/ui.o: ui.c ui.h

./objs/main.o: main.c ui.h ustreqsol.h

./objs/Getstr.o: Getstr.c

./objs/%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Note that the `ui.o` rule is probably useless and that, in the `ustreqsol.o` rule you could probably have only the `ui.h` pre-requisite.